# Change cck date field attributes

Tags: 6

I have a field in my node i.e. a cck date field with pop up. I want to control the size of this box. How do i do it. I tried hook_form_alter and found less success.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean exactly with size? Do you want to adjust the layout or do you want to change what can be typed in the box. And waht box are you talking? the input filed, pop-up, ...?

Comment: @BetaRide - I am talking about test field #size value

Comment: May be you can post your code and describe what's not working.